# Why is NSURLSessionDataTask writing to disk and how can one avoid this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have set up a NSURLSessionDataTask and observed, that on starting the task by calling `resume`, *sometimes* data is written to the disk.
I did the exactly same task with same data a few times and sometimes it was shown up, that there was written to the disk (but no reading).

Why is data written to the disk, although all objects are handled in memory?

How can one avoid to write to the disk?

Comment: How did you check for disk writing?

Comment: It is shown in the debug navigator.